# MVC Multiple DropDownLists on one page?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and I am trying to bind multiple dropdownlists on the same page, so I can grab the selected value from each and use it to search the database.  My code gives me an infinite loop.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or recommend a better way to achieve this?

**Model**:

```
public class SelectViewModel
    {

        public SelectList MakeList { get; set; }
        public SelectList ColorList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SelectViewModel objSelectModel = new SelectViewModel();
            List<Make> objMake = new List<Make>();
            List<Color> objColor = new List<Color>();

            objMake = GetMakeList();
            SelectList objBindMake = new SelectList(objMake, "MakeID", "Make1", 0);

            objColor = GetColorList();
            SelectList objBindColor = new SelectList(objColor, "ColorID", "Color1", 0);

            objSelectModel.MakeList = objBindMake;
            objSelectModel.ColorList = objBindColor;

            return View(objSelectModel);
        }



        public List<Make> GetMakeList()
        {
            var query = from m in makeRepository.Makes
                        select m;
            var makes = query.ToList();
            return makes;
        }

        public List<Color> GetColorList()
        {
            var query = from c in colorRepository.Colors
                        select c;
            var colors = query.ToList();
            return colors;
        }
```

**View**:

```
@model MvcApplication1.WebUI.Models.SelectViewModel
  Make : @Html.DropDownList("Make", new SelectList(Model.MakeList, "Value", "Text", Model.MakeList.SelectedValue))

  Color: @Html.DropDownList("Color", new SelectList(Model.ColorList, "Value", "Text", Model.ColorList.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "infinite loop"? What happens? How do you know it's an infinite loop? I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a breakpoint and stepping through the source?

Comment: The only obvious incorrect part is making a SelectList out of a SelectList, but that should not cause an infinite loop - it's just unnecessary.

Comment: I did put in break points and GetMakeList and GetColorList get called over and over instead of just once.

Comment: how many records are returned from database by "GetMakeList" and "GetColorList"? DropDownList is having some issues in IE if you prefill them with hundreds of items. But without knowing the rough numbers, I can't reckon that may be a problem in your code.

Comment: No.  It was less than 10 records for each DropDownList.  I figured out a way to do it and I am going to post it below.  If anyone can suggest and improvements or a better way to achieve this, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Model
public class SelectViewModel
    {
        public string MakeId { get; set; }
        public string ColorId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MakeList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ColorList { get; set; }
    }

//Controller
        public PartialViewResult Index()
        {

            var query = makeRepository.Makes.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.MakeID),
                Text = c.Make1,
                Selected = c.MakeID.Equals(3)
            });

            var query1 = colorRepository.Colors.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.ColorID),
                Text = c.Color1,
                Selected = c.ColorID.Equals(3)
            });

            var model = new SelectViewModel
            {
                MakeList = query.AsEnumerable(),
                ColorList = query1.AsEnumerable()
            };
            return PartialView(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SelectViewModel model)
        {
            // here you can get the selected values
            return Content("Thanks for selecting make id: " + model.MakeId + "and color id:" + model.ColorId);
        }

//View
@model MvcApplication1.WebUI.Models.SelectViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MakeId, Model.MakeList, "--Select One--")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ColorId, Model.ColorList, "--Select One--")
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```